# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Offline update

Tags: offline, update-alternatives, apt-mirror

1. How to update/upgrade Ubuntu Server 16.04 offline ?.
2. I have created a local mirror (150GB) using apt-mirror.  How to configure offline server/system to update the system.

Thanks in advance